# Handle null values

Tags: c#, sql-server, null

I have a command that display the Name based on EmpID:

```
using (SqlCommand SqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select EmpID, Name from EmpTable where EmpID = @a", myDatabaseConnection))
                {
                    SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", textBox1.Text);
                    using (SqlDataReader sqlreader = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {

                        if (sqlreader.Read())
                        {
                            Namelabel.Text = sqlreader.GetString(sqlreader.GetOrdinal("Name"));
                        }
                    }
                }
```

How I will handle if name data is `null`? Like if data is `null` `Namelabel.Text = ""`.

Comment: What is there to handle?  I would imagine the code you already have would work just fine if the output is null.

Comment: what do u want if its null?

Comment: What you want to check for null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
Namelabel.Text = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(sqlreader.GetString(sqlreader.GetOrdinal("Name"))) ? sqlreader.GetString(sqlreader.GetOrdinal("Name")) : "Value not found";
```

This will give some output if the value in the database is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

You can [use `IsDBNull()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull.aspx) to check for a null value before trying to read that value as a string.  Something like this:

```
if (sqlreader.Read())
{
    var columnOrdinal = sqlreader.GetOrdinal("Name");
    if (sqlReader.IsDBNull(columnOrdinal))
        NameLabel.Text = string.Empty;
    else
        Namelabel.Text = sqlreader.GetString(columnOrdinal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just test for null as you read.

```
 if (sqlreader.Read())
 {
      Namelabel.Text = sqlreader.GetString(sqlreader.GetOrdinal("Name")==null?"":sqlreader.GetOrdinal("Name"));
 }
```